# Why haven't I seen the arm tablet being brushed into the ubuntu system

Tags: system-installation, tablet, arm

It seems that I have never seen anyone try to swipe the ubuntu system onto the devices of MediaTek or Qualcomm CPUs. Why? I am trying to purchase a 2-in-1 device, but the 2-in-1 device of x86 seems to be unsatisfactory in terms of both endurance and heat. I wonder whether the arm tablet device flushed into ubuntu is satisfactory?

Comment: Welcome. This isn't a discussion forum, but a [Q&A site](https://askubuntu.com/tour). If you want to discuss future hardware prospects etc., try the [Ubuntu forum](https://ubuntuforums.org/).

Comment: Brushed? Swipe? Flushed? What are these supposed to mean here?

Comment: @muru Factory installed ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Generally, tablets share the same hardware issues as phones that make most incompatible or unsatisfactory with Ubuntu: Unusual components and architectures that are unfamiliar to the Linux kernel.

Original Equipment Manufacturers (OEMs) are encouraged, but not required, to contribute their hardware compatibility code to the Linux kernel. Canonical employs a small engineering team in Taiwan to test hardware and assist interested OEMs with that task. Some OEMs do, some OEMs don't.